# Swift - Getting data from firebase realtime database after method return

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

Good afternoon. I'm learning to develop on iOS. Before, I did it on Android, but now I couldn't do it here. The variable always returns "". I understand that these are asynchronous processes, and that in general, such functions should be done without a return parameter, but how to do this I don't clearly understand.

//In swiftUI, I just call the method

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class GetGarbageInfo {
    func getInfo(path:String) -> String{
        var result = ""
        
        let rootReference = Database.database().reference()
        let garbageReference = rootReference.child("GarbageInformation").child(path).child("body")
        
        garbageReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (DataSnapshot) in
            result = DataSnapshot.value as? String ?? "0"
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `completion handler` instead of `return` (as you've already noticed yourself):

```
class GetGarbageInfo {

    // add completion, remove return type
    func getInfo(path: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        var result = ""
        
        let rootReference = Database.database().reference()
        let garbageReference = rootReference.child("GarbageInformation").child(path).child("body")
        
        garbageReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (DataSnapshot) in
            result = DataSnapshot.value as? String ?? "0"
        }

        // return the result in the completion
        completion(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for a stupid question.. but how can i get the result in the UI?(

Comment: @LeonidSpiridonov That is a different question for which you should create a new post (this is a StackOverflow rule: 1 question per post).